# VBA Run Time Error 424: Object Required when trying to delete blank rows in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

From research, I found that the error is caused because an object cannot be recognized. I set the range to a specific column, thinking that the column("E") couldn't be identified possibly, but I still have the same error. How can I fix this error, or is there any better way to delete the rows in the worksheet? Thanks in advance.

Here's the program:

```
Sub DeleteBlanks()

Dim rng As Range
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("IPIC-DATA-2.xlsx")

ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Set rng = Range("E:E")

ws.Columns(rng).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: you are passing a Range object as an argument expecting an integer value. The best way to debug your own code is to 1) read up on the actual error (but sometimes this can be cyrptic). 2) read up on the methods you are using so you understand the arguments better. Just type: `rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete` Also, see my edits to the title of your question. It will be way more SEO friendly for others.

Comment: I'll try that method next time I need to debug. The edits on my question were very helpful, as I'm new to SO. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is a bit off. Define the worksheet and reference that. `rng` is already defined as a range (with reference to a sheet) so does not need to be wrapped in a sheet or column.

```
Sub DeleteBlanks()

Dim rng As Range
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("IPIC-DATA-2.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("E:E")

On Error Resume Next 'avoid error if there are no blanks
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0

wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for your help.